# Avoid Hard Coding Controller name Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am a beginner in angular..I have a requirement to avoid hard coding any names in the app.. I have used

```
myapp.constant("constantName",
{
    "name":"name1"
});
```

to avoid hard coding html..I would also like to avoid hard coding controller names also...

example :

```
myapp.controller("IndexCtrl",function($scope){});
```

Instead of having the string `IndexCtrl` in the controller, is there any way to define something like this

```
myapp.controller(constantName.controller,function($scope){})
```

where the constant will be

```
myapp.constant("constantName",
{
    "name":"name1",
    "controller" : "IndexCtrl"
});
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your requirement seems possibly misguided and maybe ridiculous.

Comment: How will you manage injections with this scheme? You will need "named" constants, so um, how is that better?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anything quite like that before, but what I have seen (and done) is define your controller like so:

```
(function(){
    var controllerName = 'MyCtrl';
    angular.module('myModule').controller(controllerName, function($scope, $log){
        // Now in my controller I have full access the controller name 
        // this can be used for any logging that I may need to do
        $log.debug('something broke in ' + controllerName);
    });
})();
```